# App not appearing in iCloud “Manage Storage” list

Tags: ios, cocoa, icloud

My application was released and use iCloud but the App isn't appearing in the iCloud preferences (Settings.app > iCloud > Storage & Backup > Manage Store > Documents & Data)

The sync is up and works great but I don't have access to the date of my app.

Comment: Did you ever happen to find a solution to this?

Comment: Adding iCloud support is (still) a mess.

Answer (score 0):

Apps will appear in iCloud "Manage Storage" list only when its iCloud container have a non-empty file.

Comment: This is not correct, because I have a long list of apps in *Manage Storage* section of iCould's that have *No Data*.