# App Not in iCloud "Manage Storage" List

Tags: ios, icloud, data-storage

I'm trying to exclude all unnecessary files & folders from iCloud backup in my app that's rejected for this reason, however following the instructions to check the backup data size, it's not being consistent about displaying the app in the apps list in `Settings > iCloud > Storage and Backup > Manage Storage > [Current Device] > Show All Apps`.

I've been trying this under all these circumstances:

1. Delete the app and install it from scratch and launch it and then check iCloud
2. Stop the app from Xcode, but keep it installed and then check iCloud
3. Launch the app by tapping on the icon while the app is **NOT** being run by Xcode and then check iCloud
4. Delete the whole app and then check iCloud (and surprisingly see the app listed there! either with the icon image or without it)
5. Killing the app or the Settings app before repeating these options
6. Waiting for a while or checking it immediately after launching the app

For testing purposes, I have **NOT** excluded some of the files/folders from backup, and nevertheless, I can see The inconsistency is about having or not having the app in among the apps in that list, so for example I try doing #2; but the result is not the same every time; i.e. the first time the app might not appear in the list, but the second time it may; or vice versa.

[image]

The inconsistency is about having or not having the app in among the apps in that list, so for example I try doing #2; but the result is not the same every time; i.e. the first time the app might not appear in the list, but the second time it may; or vice versa.

Can this be fixed?

P.S. I spent a long while searching before asking this question, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487975/app-not-appearing-in-icloud-manage-storage-list) with no accepted/upvoted answers is the only thing I found.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Same issue here.

Answer (score 0):

After I forgot to add it (and got rejected), I included the tag not to back up to iCloud when saving some files. But even without the tag added, they didn't seem to be backing up to the cloud after inspecting via the advised method:

**Settings > iCloud > Storage and Backup > Manage Storage > [Current Device] > Show All Apps**

I think that advice is old, or at best, unclear. I found more luck here:

**Settings > General > Storage & iCloud Usage**

Here in '**Storage > Manage Storage**' it says I'm using 82MB (in the list) and 9MB after clicking through further inspection (why do they differ?). Using iExplorer to go in and have a look, the 9MB is closer to the truth, I don't have 70MB worth of code!

Then in '**ICloud > Manage Storage > Show All**' I can't even see the app. With, and without the do not back up tag, it doesn't seem to make any difference.

My advice:

1. add the do not back up tag
2. save to custom library subfolder
3. hope...